# Mongodb lookup not fetch from other table

Tags: typescript, mongodb

I have two table: question and topic. I'd like join this two table:

```
let result = await Question.Question.aggregate([{
    $lookup: { from: 'topic', localField: 'topic_id', foreignField: '_id', as: 'topic' }
}]);
```

But response is not contain the required topic document.

```
0
_id "644651ddb96106c0065bf539"
question    "question 1"
topic_id    "64464779b31146ced5d0ebbe"
explanation "programs"
__v 0
topic   []
1   
_id "64466045c886fb9d5be3f442"
question    "Which is programing languge"
topic_id    "64466021c886fb9d5be3f440"
explanation "Choose programing languages"
__v 0
topic   []
```

My Question class is the following:

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
const questionSchema = new Schema({ 
            question: {
                type: String,
                required:true,
            },
            topic_id: {
                type: String,
                required:true,
            },
            explanation: {
                type: String,
                required:true,
            },
});

const Question = model("question", questionSchema);
export default { Question };
```

The Topic class is the following:

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

const topicSchema = new Schema({ 
            name: {
                type: String,
                required:true,
            },
});

const Topic = model("topic", topicSchema);
export default { Topic };
```

The Topic table content:

```
_id
64464779b31146ced5d0ebbe
name
"Programming"
__v
0

_id
64466021c886fb9d5be3f440
name
"Programing languages"
__v
0
```

Please help me find the bug. I use Typescript and I don't understand why not work.

Comment: The `topic_id` is string and the `_id` on `topic` collection is an `ObjectId`. You can save the  `topic_id` as `ObjectId` or you can use `$lookup` with pipeline

Comment: import { Schema, model, Types } from "mongoose";
topic_id: {
        type: Types.ObjectId,
},